# Accessing Azure B2C-protected odata feed using PowerBI desktop / excel

Tags: odata, azure-ad-b2c, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on OData/webAPI service implementation. PowerBI desktop app will be used to retrieve info from the service using odata feed datasource.
Service in protected by Azure B2C auth. Accessing odata endpoints using browser works fine - after signing in access is granted. But when I'm trying to connect to the feed using powerbi desktop by performing signin attempt, it reports that token source is not trusted.

[picture related: sign in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUNO.png)

Also, in case of single-tenant Azure AD auth (not B2C) usage, authentication in PowerBI worked though.
So, is there a possibility to make PowerBI work with Azure AD B2C (to make it trust the token source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Azure AD B2C does not issue tokens which Microsoft first party services recognize. AAD B2C is used to protect you **own** services which you supply to your **own** customers.

If you would like your customers to have self service sign up, and access Power Bi resource, then have your front end web app talk to a backend API. Protect the front end and backend with AAD B2C. That backend API should use client_credentials to authenticate via AAD endpoints to access Power Bi data on behalf of the user.